# Text classifier with word splitting using StanfordNLP classifier

Tags: java, classification, stanford-nlp, text-classification

After a quite successful start to StanfordNLP (and with the german module) I tried out classifying numerical data. This also exited with good results.

At least I tried to set up a classifier for categorizing text documents (both mails and scanned documents) but this was quite frustrating. What I want to do is working with a classifier on word base, not with n-grams. My training file has two columns: First with the category of the text, second with the text itself, without tabs or line breakers.

The properties file has the following content:

```
1.splitWordsWithPTBTokenizer=true
1.splitWordsRegexp=false
1.splitWordsTokenizerRegexp=false
1.useSplitWords=true
```

But when I start training the classifier like this...

```
    ColumnDataClassifier cdc = new ColumnDataClassifier("classifier.properties");
    Classifier<String, String> classifier =
        cdc.makeClassifier(cdc.readTrainingExamples("data.train"));
```

...then I get many lines starting with the following hint:

```
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.classify.ColumnDataClassifier - Warning: regexpTokenize pattern false didn't match on
```

My questions are:

1) Any idea what is wrong with my properties? I think, my training file is okay.

2) I want to use the words/tokens that I got from CoreNLP with the german model. Is this possible?

Thanks for any answers!

Answer (score 1):

The numbering is correct, you don't have to put 2's in the beginning of the lines, as one other answer states. 1 stands for first **data** column, not for the first column in general in your training file (which is the category). Options with a 2. in the beginning would be for the second data column, or the third column in general in your training file - which you don't have.

I don't know about using the words/tokens you got from CoreNLP, but it also took me a while to find out how to use word n-grams, so maybe for some people this will be helpful:

```
# regex for splitting on whitespaces
1.splitWordsRegexp=\\s+

# enable word n-grams, just like character n-grams are used
1.useSplitWordNGrams=true

# range of values of n for your n-grams. (1-grams to 4-grams in this example)
1.minWordNGramLeng=1
1.maxWordNGramLeng=4

# use word 1-grams (just single words as features), obsolete if you're using
# useSplitWordNGrams with minWordNGramLeng=1
1.useSplitWords=true

# use adjacent word 2-grams, obsolete if you're using
# useSplitWordNGrams with minWordNGramLeng<=2 and maxWordNGramLeng>=2
1.useSplitWordPairs=true

# use word 2-grams in every possible combination, not just adjacent words
1.useAllSplitWordPairs=true

# same as the pairs but 3-grams, also not just adjacent words
1.useAllSplitWordTriples=true
```

for more information have a look at http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/classify/ColumnDataClassifier.html

Answer (score 0):

You are saying your training file has two columns, first with the category of the text, second with the text itself. Based on this, your properties file is incorrect, because you are adding rules to the first column there.

Modify your properties to be applied to the column where the text is as follows:

```
2.splitWordsWithPTBTokenizer=true
2.splitWordsRegexp=false
2.splitWordsTokenizerRegexp=false
2.useSplitWords=true
```

Furthermore, I would suggest to work through the [Software/Classifier/20 Newsgroups](http://nlp.stanford.edu/wiki/Software/Classifier/20_Newsgroups) wiki, this shows some practical examples on how to work with the Stanford Classifier, and how to set up options through the properties file.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try out both in the next days.

Comment: Sorry, but using colum number 2 instead of 1 leads to an exception: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Error: Line has too few tab-separated columns (2) for 3 columns required by specified properties: abc def [...]" Looks as I should read you linked manual.

Comment: Take a look at the source code where this exception is thrown at http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/edu.stanford.nlp/stanford-corenlp/3.5.2/edu/stanford/nlp/classify/ColumnDataClassifier.java , something could be wrong with your input. Do you have only two columns, separated by tab? No tab in the data itself? I really recommend to work through the wiki, it shows how to step-by-step use the Stanford NLP classifier.